# Check a great number of IMAP accounts at once in Python

Tags: python, imap, scalability, email-client

I have to write a litte daemon that can check multiple (could be up to several hundred) email accounts for new messages.

My thoughts so far:

I could just create a new thread for each connection, using [imapclient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) for retrieving the messages every x seconds, or use IMAP IDLE where possible. I also could modify imapclient a bit and `select()` over all the sockets where IMAP IDLE is activated using a single thread only.

Are there any better approaches for solving this task?

Comment: `twisted.mail` might be useful for this too. http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/mail/examples/imap4client.py

Comment: What platform are you on? And is "several hundred" closer to, say, 300 or 800?

Comment: @frb: looks usefull, thx!

Comment: @abarnert: Unix (but the more independent, the better). Connections can get closer to 800.

Comment: OK, if you want 800 sockets on both Unix and Windows and want to be able to support low-end systems, yeah, I think either `gevent` or `twisted.mail` is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only you'd asked a few months from now, because Python 3.3.1 will probably have a spiffy new async API. See http://code.google.com/p/tulip/ for the current prototype, but you probably don't want to use it yet.

If you're on Windows, you may be able to handle a few hundred threads without a problem. If so, it's probably the simplest solution. So, try it and see.

If you're on Unix, you probably want to use `poll` instead of `select`, because `select` scales badly when you get into the hundreds of connections. (`epoll` on linux or `kqueue` on Mac/BSD are even more scalable, but it doesn't usually matter until you get into the thousands of connections.)

But there are a few things you might want to consider before doing this yourself:

- [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)
- [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org)
- [Monocle](https://github.com/saucelabs/monocle)
- [gevent](http://www.gevent.org)

`Twisted` is definitely the hardest of these to get into—but it also comes with an IMAP client ready to go, among hundreds of other things, so if you're willing to deal with a bit of a learning curve, you may be done a lot faster.

`Tornado` feels the most like writing native `select`-type code. I don't actually know all of the features it comes with; it may have an IMAP client, but if not, you'll be hacking up `imapclient` the same way you were considering with `select`.

`Monocle` sits on top of either `Twisted` or `Tornado`, and lets you write code that's kind of like what's coming in 3.3.1, on top of Twisted or Tornado (although actually, you can do the same thing directly in Twisted with `inlineCallbacks`, it's just that the docs disccourage you from learning that without learning everything else first). Again, you'd be hacking up `imapclient` here. (Or using `Twisted`'s IMAP client instead… but at that point, you might as well use `Twisted` directly.)

`gevent` lets you write code that's almost the same as threaded (or synchronous) code and just magically makes it asynchronous. You may need to hack up `imapclient` a bit, but it may be as simple as running the magic monkeypatching utility, and that's it. And beyond that, you write the same code you'd write with threading, except that you create a bunch of greenlets instead of a bunch of threads, and you get an order of magnitude or two better scalability.

If you're looking for the absolute maximum scalability, you'll probably want to parallelize and multiplex at the same time (e.g., run 8 processes, each using `gevent`, on Unix, or attach a native threadpool to IOCP on Windows), but for a few hundred connections this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I think I'll have to write my own mail client if I want to use `Monocle` or similar? Guess I will take a look into `Twisted` - looks very promising :)

Comment: @snøreven: I've updated the answer with more info. Yes, you have to hack up `imapclient` or write your own, with most of them. But with `gevent`, you may be able to just magic-monkeypatch `imapclient` and use it as if you were writing threads. I'd look at both that and `Twisted`.